# Phantom_Omni with Ros

Tags: ubuntu-precise, rosrun, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to use a Phantom Omni device with ROS, but when I run the omni node terminal shows next message and nothing happens more, the prompt doesn't return and the cursor keeps flashing.

INFO 1374828811.829641606: Found PHANTOM Omni.

INFO 1374828811.881649887: HD_CALIBRATION_INKWELL..

INFO 1374828811.883714328: Calibrating.. (put stylus in well)

INFO 1374828811.883780678:

Calibration complete.

Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68602/phantom_omni-with-ros/) by [jalvarofa](https://answers.ros.org/users/5536/jalvarofa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2013-07-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-07-24**:
Seems error message got lost. Please update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That is correct behavior. The messages are showing that device was found and successfully calibrated.

To read coordinates and buttons states you have to subscribe to `omni1_pose` and `omni1_button` topics respectively. To command force to Omni use `omni1_force_feedback` topic.

If you are not sure how to do aforementioned, please go through [beginner tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials).

For a quick test you also may want to try:

```
$ rostopic echo omni1_pose
```

This will output current pose (position + orientation) of Omni end-effector to the terminal.

---

**EDIT: (summarizing comments below)**

On Ubuntu 12.04 and higher a JUJU Phantom Device Drivers (PDD) have to be used. The necessary files can be found on [SensAble Developer Support Center](http://dsc.sensable.com).

Since original [phantom_omni](http://www.ros.org/wiki/phantom_omni) package seems to be broken a more generic [sensable_phantom](https://github.com/bgromov/sensable_phantom) can be used instead, both on Fuerte and Groovy. The package suppose to work with any Phantom models (Omni, Premium 1.5, Premium 3.0 etc).

To install the latter on Fuerte:

```
# Go to sandbox directory in the rosbuild workspace
$ roscd && cd sandbox

# Clone `rosbuild' branch of package
$ git clone -b rosbuild https://github.com/bgromov/sensable_phantom.git

# Update rospack cache
$ rospack profile

# Compile the package
$ rosmake sensable_phantom
```

P.S. Something wrong with AskBot. The link on the `git clone` line should be without surrounding HTML-tags.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2013-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jalvarofa](https://answers.ros.org/users/5536/jalvarofa/) on 2013-07-29**:
When I try omni1_button and I press the buttons works good. But when I try omni1_pose and I move the phantom's omni stylus the coordenates don't change, always it is 0.0

header: seq: 122795 stamp: secs: 1375096548 nsecs: 228468035 frame_id: omni1_link6 pose: position: x: 0.0 y: 0.0 z: 0.0 orientation: x: 0.0 y: 0.0 z: 0.0 w: 1.0

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-07-29**:
What version of the OpenHaptics do you use? Does the `PHANToMTest` utility works on your system?

**Comment by [jalvarofa](https://answers.ros.org/users/5536/jalvarofa/) on 2013-07-30**:
I use v3.0 in Ubuntu 12.04, Linux JUJU PDD 32-bits and ROS Fuerte. PHANToMTest works good.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-07-31**:
What about Phantom Device Drivers (PDD)? I'm using PDD v4.3 and OpenHaptics v3.0, but 64-bit version... And with this PDD 4.3 I cannot run PHANToMTest at all, so I guess you have previous version of PDD.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-07-31**:
... As far as I know new version was never released officially, but you can download it from [SensAble Developer Support Center](http://dsc.sensable.com/) (don't remember exact link).

**Comment by [jalvarofa](https://answers.ros.org/users/5536/jalvarofa/) on 2013-08-18**:
Yes, I use this "unofficial" version called Linux JUJU PDD 32-bits and all works good (PHANToMTest, omni1_button, some examples, etc) but omni1_pose doesn't work

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-08-18**:
Honestly I didn't use original `phantom_omni` for a long time, but my own [reimplemented version](https://github.com/bgromov/sensable_phantom). If you do not need specific features of original package you maybe interested to try that one. For Fuerte checkout `rosbuild` branch.

**Comment by [jalvarofa](https://answers.ros.org/users/5536/jalvarofa/) on 2013-08-19**:
ok, I'll try to use your version to see how works, thank you very much.

EDIT: Your version works in ROS Fuerte or ROS Groovy?

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-08-19**:
Both. As I mentioned above, for Fuerte you have to use `rosbuild` branch of repository. To do that use the following command `git clone -b rosbuild https://github.com/bgromov/sensable_phantom.git`

**Comment by [jalvarofa](https://answers.ros.org/users/5536/jalvarofa/) on 2013-08-21**:
Perfect!! topic's pose works!!! thank you very much!! I have a new problem that I elevate to question.